# Pjsip-jni compile and import to eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sip, pjsip

I am trying to use the `pjsip-jni wrapper` for `eclipse` to make Android sip based client.

I have tried to goggle how to compile and use it with eclipse, but have not yet found the right track. Any information would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You can see what is done in [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild) open source project. In this project you have an example of full soft phone that uses the pjsip-jni wrapper. You can even send an email to the developers group, and ask the programmer(Regis - a really nice guy) himself. [Here is a link to the code.](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple)

Comment: That project is quite big and difficult to grasp and understand. What would be ideal is a simple pjsip.jar file compiled already that can be used but unfortunatly it doesnt exist